# Chinese writing when writing to files?

Tags: ruby, windows, encoding, internationalization

Using Ruby and Windows Vista, I sometimes get what look likes Chinese writing - particularly when writing to HTML files.
Does anybody know what causes this?  Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue... do you have any samples?

Comment: No I do not have any samples but this happens using various modes w w+ r r+ a ab and using pos = and .insert together with some very basic file writng taken from popular Ruby books. I do not

Comment: You're not encountering the [Bush hid the facts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) mojibake issue are you?

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming these are UTF-8 files).
In UTF-8 a character can take upto 6 bytes. If the insertion of text using pos= is targeted in the middle of a multi-byte character, the rest of the document will be garbage.

If the position you are targetting contains a byte starting with 10, you are in the [middle of a char](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design).

Comment: Addition: If this is the case, the solution would be to switch to ruby 1.9 and use character based methods rather than byte based methods. But since the OP does not provide what is to be done, we cannot suggest any further.

Comment: That may be the answer steenslag but I have also written to empty files and had the garbage. A